# setTabListener inside the Fragment class

Tags: android, android-fragments

```
public class MyridesFragment extends android.app.Fragment implements
        ActionBar.TabListener {

    FragmentActivity myContext;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private android.app.ActionBar actionBar;

    private String[] tabs = { "All Rides", "Upcoming", "Complted" };

    public MyridesFragment() {
    }

    public void onViewCreated(View view,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(myContext.getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(android.app.ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(this.MyridesFragment)); //getting error here
        }
}
```

As newbie to android,try to do swipe tabs,above is my code.i could able to give setTablistener to my tabs.Can anyone please help me to resolve